# RCP 3 - Lock a toolbar menu contribution

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Currently I'm porting an RCP 3 project to RCP 4 using the compatibility in RCP 4. This has worked okay so far although I've had to make changes to a `ContributionItem` I'm using for the toolbar as `WorkbenchWindowControlContribution` is now required instead.
After changing this I have noticed that I'm now able to drag the toolbar and move it. I would like to remove the icon (with 3 dots) that allow for clicking to move the panel around.

This is how I define the menu contribution.

```
<menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
  <toolbar id="contributions.toolbar">
    <control
      class="name.of.Class"
      id="perspectiveSwitcherToolbar">
    </control>
  </toolbar>
</menuContribution>
```

How can I make the toolbar locked?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclispe e4 we acheive this by adding tags in Application.e4xmi model.

1. Click on your ToolBar
2. Go to the supplementary section for that toolbar like shown below.

[image]

3. Enter the tag `"NoMove"` without space in the New value text box under Tags section like shown below and click on Add button.

[image]

Now save and restart the application the control(3 dots) which is used to move the panel will be disabled.

[image]

To achieve the similar in e3 please visit this discussion link [Remove ToolBar Drag](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1076231/).

Comment: The problem with this is that we don't have the time to move to RCP 4 yet as there would be a lot to change. If this can't be done in the compatibility mode then this will have to be the approach. We will have to stick to RCP 3 for the moment and when we have time migrate completely to 4.

Comment: @Michael, Maybe this discussion link https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1076231/  might help you solving the issue. I have edited my answer and provided the link there also for your reference.

Comment: After looking at the linked page it seems this is for somebody who has it not being draggable and is trying to make it draggable. I might be missing it but I can't see how to make it draggable from that.